# How can use the result for compiled kernel to another machine(has different distribution )

Tags: linux-kernel, build-automation

I have 2 machine A and B. A installed ubuntu. B installed redhat.
Now, I made the kernel on A. use:

```
make O=xxx_dir/ &&
make O=xxx_dir/ modules
```

Then, copy xxx_dir to B machine.
Please tall me, how can I use  xxx_dir to run:

```
make install
make modules_install
```

For a word. That is compile in A and install to B.

**I need to build a build-server, what storad some different version of kernel. I want send the result of compile to client machine. Then, install it.**

Thanks.

Comment: Bad idea.  Not only are the kernel versions different, but distributions make their own changes to the kernel.  You really need to compile the module on a machine running the same kernel.  Use a VM on your A machine with a duplicate OS if you can't put a compiler on B.

Comment: I need to build a build-server, what storad some different version of kernel. I want send the result of compile to client machine. Then, install it.